# Deploying angular app with fastapi and port 0.0.0.0 disables ui

Tags: angular, angularjs, routes, fastapi

I want to deploy an angular app with a fastapi frontend via docker.
The app works fine when deploying via unicorn on localhost.
However, as soon as I try to deploy it on a different host (0.0.0.0), the application still finds the ui root, but does not display any components.

```
uvicorn main:app --port 8000 --reload <-- UI shows

uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload <-- UI does not show components
```

I build the angular app with the command:

```
ng build --base-href ./
```

and I mount it to fastapi with the command:

```
app.mount(
"/frontend",
StaticFiles(
    directory=str("frontend/dist/frontend"),
    html=True,
),
name="frontend",
)
```

Is it the base-href making issues here?
It is finding the index.html and displaying it with a header bar, however it fails to populate it with items.

So far I have tried to add the host to the allowed origins.
I do not have a host set in the angular.json.

The file structure looks like this:

```
app
├──frontend
│   ├──src
│   │  ├──index.html
│   │  ├──...
│   ├──angular.json
│   ├──...
├──main.py
├──...
```

The same issue arises when I try to serve it via 0.0.0.0 with ng.serve

Comment: what can you see in the console, and in the network tabs? It seems like a CORS issue at first. ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 does not work but ng serve does?

Comment: Hi Forest,
The outputs look similar.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59994 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 Not Modified
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59994 - "GET /runtime.89bfad0fe920d2c9.js HTTP/1.1" 304 Not Modified
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59994 - "GET /polyfills.499bf1a0a255fd80.js HTTP/1.1" 304 Not Modified
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59995 - "GET /main.116797295d563a34.js HTTP/1.1" 304 Not Modified
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59995 - "GET /styles.c3d4b450f6ad917b.css HTTP/1.1" 304 Not Modified

By the way, if i host 0n 0.0.0.0 it works as long as i still got to localhost (127...)

Comment: It looks like a CORS issue:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/workflows' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.